# Any apps that auto sync local to remote on save for mac?

Tags: macos, sync, ftp, sftp, watch

Does Panic's Transmit has this feature? For example you set it to watch a particular folder, and any file changes in that folder gets uploaded to the remote automatically?

They were highly recommended few years back, but seems to have gone all quiet lately?

Or any other apps that does this? I'm aware of YummyFTP that has a watcher, but it requires 2 purchases and the UI doesn't seem high quality.

I own ForkLift 2 but there's no watcher or auto sync feature. Unless someone knows how to write a service or script out of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync
```

has all the functions one would need. You will need to know how to write a script, though, to fit your needs.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html